# Unable to upload My APP on Google play

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am unable to upload my App with version name: 2.62G and version code:90. Previous version in the market is : Version Name: 2.60 and Version code: 88.
In manifest file i am using this:

```
android:versionCode="90"
    android:versionName="2.62" >
    <!-- android:versionCode="40" -->
    <!-- android:versionName="1.12" -->
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11"
        android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
.................
..................
```

For detailed issues, picture is attached.
Please help me,what am i doing wrong? Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
android:versionCode="1"
```

you are using this in comments.Remove comments.

Comment: Version name should be 2.6.2 i think not 2.62

Comment: And have you exported apk file using new keystore or using existing keystore?

Comment: thats wrong if you want to deploy your app in android market you have to use your own keystore.click on create new keystore.The existing keystore is only for testing on emulator